# R: Hiding info in the output of a function (like how the lm function works)

Tags: r

So a quick example of the output from the lm function:

```
> y<-rnorm(10)
> x<-y+rnorm(10)
> L<-lm(y ~ x)       #Creates the object L
> L                  #Gives only a small summary of L

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
    0.03514      0.77202  

> residuals(L)             # Gives all the raw data on the residuals of L
           1            2            3            4            5 
 0.379071438  0.357077188 -0.270606886 -0.138712332  0.167195314 
           6            7            8            9           10 
-0.017580418 -0.859508221 -0.008648384  0.532864345 -0.141152045 
>
```

So what's going on here? "L" is the output of the lm function, and by entering L into the console it gives a summary. However, when outputting residuals(L), it gives additional information not found in L. Somehow, the object "L" contains this information but it is obscured. **I would like to figure out how to do this in my code**.

**How do I go about creating an object "Myobject" that, when called, only gives a summary, but when applying some function "moredetails(Myobject)" gives additional details.**

I can see this being very handy when it comes to complicated analyses, yet I can't find anything in the  source code for lm that would indicate how this is done. I also feel like I'm missing a keyword which would make searching for this problem much easier.

Comment: You need to investigate object-oriented programming in R. A good starting point might be [the OOP section of Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/oo.html).

Comment: This is a characteristic of S3 classes, when you run `L` what you are in fact running is `print.lm(L)`, the `print` method for objects of class `"lm"`. If you want to see the code of `print.lm` run `getAnywhere(print.lm)`. But start with the suggestion of @neilfws.