# R: revealing the contents of a S3/S4 object

Tags: r, object

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52379537/r-hiding-info-in-the-output-of-a-function-like-how-the-lm-function-works) I asked about S3/S4 class objects, of the type where inputting the object name gives a summary of the object rather than all the data stored within the object.

**I want to be able to find all the info that such an object contains. Is there a function that allows me to do this?**

To take my previous example: the lm function.

```
> y<-rnorm(10)
> x<-y+rnorm(10)
> L<-lm(y ~ x)       #Creates the object L
> L
```

This gives the summarised output:

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
    0.03514      0.77202
```

Whereas I want to obtain all the information stored in L.

**Note that this is an example for illustration purposes. I am not after specific pieces of information about the lm function, but rather a way for revealing the entire contents of a given object in general**.

Comment: try: `attributes(L)`

Comment: `str( L )` will show you everything inside it

Comment: also `unclass( L )` might help